# How does the phrase "to be sectioned" originate?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, mental-health

Of course it derives from the relevant *section* of the mental health act that bestows the powers of "sectioning", but why is that term used to refer to "being detained for mental health reasons", rather than to "having one's vehicle seized" or "being searched upon reasonable suspicion for dangerous items", under the corresponding statutory sections that bestow the relevant  powers for those procedures?

How did this nomenclature of verbifying section in this way come to be?

Comment: This may be more suitable over at ELU under the [language-evolution](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-evolution) tag

Comment: I don't object to migration though cannot see how it is any more suited to either of the two venues  than the other.

Comment: See also "scheduled monument", and possibly "section house".

Answer (score 2):

The Oxford English Dictionary provides a definition of "section" as a transitive verb in this sense:

> to cause (a person) to be compulsorily detained in a psychiatric hospital in accordance with the provisions of the relevant section of the Mental Health Act of 1983 or (formerly) that of 1959

The OED does not discuss the etymology but the earliest listed usage is from 1984 in the British Medical Journal: "Before the 1983 Act came into being no social worker ever refused my request to come and see a patient with a view to sectioning the patient under the old section 29."

This is an example of what Bryan Garner labels a *functional shift* (see *Garner's Modern English Usage*). The shift from a noun to a verb (and therefore sometimes participle) is somewhat common. The resulting use straddles the line between slang and jargon before becoming mainstream.

Other examples:

- Googled
- mirandize (to read the *Miranda* warning to a person)
- violate (to return a person to prison for a violation of parole conditions: "*I could keep him from being violated on his probation*" (OED))
- DMCAd (to have content removed from a website pursuant to a notice under the Digital Millenium Copyright Act)

There is no uniform way that these shifts happen and I cannot find any historical tracing of how the shift in usage you are asking about developed.